# Compare regression coefficients among subgroups

Tags: regression

I have a following issue. Suppose that I would like to know, how age of a marathon runner impacts his or her final marathon time. I run two separated regressions (for men and women):

Men: $time = \alpha_{0}^{M} + \beta_{1}^{M} \cdot age$

Women: $time = \alpha_{0}^{W} + \beta_{1}^{W} \cdot age$

Of course, men are faster than women. Based on my summary statistics I know that average marathon runners time is $men = \dfrac{2}{3} women$.

My goal is to see if age variable more affects men' or women' time. Is it statistically correct to test if $\beta_{1}^{M} \cdot \dfrac{2}{3} = \beta_{1}^{W} $ ? And the same for the standard error of $\beta_{1}^{M}$ and $\beta_{1}^{W}$ ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a single model for both males and females with an interaction term

$$
time = \alpha_0 + \beta_1 I_W + \beta_2 age + \beta_3 I_W age + \varepsilon
$$

where $I_W$ is an indicator variable that is $0$ for men and $1$ for woman. In such a case $\beta_1 I_W$ tells you about the difference in the intercept for males vs females and $\beta_3 I_W age$ tells you about the difference in slopes. The hypothesis tests for them are available out of the box.

Comment: Thank you, I see your point with adding the interaction term. Just to be sure: Is my idea totally wrong? Or can we assume that betas should be also by 2/3 different?

Comment: @vojtam it is not totally wrong, but the above is a more standard and kosher approach.

Comment: the reason the interaction approach is preferred to what you proposed is that beta 3 explicitly tests the question you are interested in: "if age variable more affects men' or women' time." No need for post hoc tests or anything else. If it's positive and significant then age has a bigger effect for women than men. But one warning - center "age" around the mean before you do this, otherwise the sex coefficient will tell you the effect of sex for a person who is zero years old.